# UP dating the count from a user making a section from a drop down menu

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi I have a mysql database called colordb and a table in that database called colorchoic with three rows call id, color and value. The color row has eight colors stored in it they are yellow, blue, green, red, black, orange, brown, white. I then have a PHP select from that will populate select form by pulling the colors from the database. I would like to know if there is anyway of getting the user to select a color which will then add 1 to the value row. So for instance if I get six users to select their favorite color the database might look something like this table below.

The table/database before the six users select their inputs (colors).

```
**Color    Value**
   Orange    0
   Red       0
   Blue      0
   Black     0
   Yellow    0
   Green     0
   White     0
   Brown     0
```

The table/batabase after the six users select their input (colors)

```
**Color    Value**
   Orange    0
   Red       2
   Blue      1
   Black     1
   Yellow    1
   Green     1
   White     0
   Brown     0
```

this is my PHP code

```
<?php

// create a db connection 
$con = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "user", "password", "colorbd");


// Check connection
if ($con === false){
die ("ERROR: could not connect to database." . mysqli_connect_error ());
}

$sql = "SELECT color FROM colorchoice";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "color: " . $row["color"]. " <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

So what I'm trying to do is allow the user to only select a color from a select which will then add 1 to the value row each time the user selects a color.

Comment: I just  noticed  a small typo die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  should be ie('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());

Comment: can use remove the hold on this question or if its still unclear what am akin please let me know what part/parts are unclear